# Prior row depends on value of current row

Tags: mysql

The following query shows login information based on the userId. If a user closes their browser without logging off or the session expires, the logoff_date will remain null as in the example below.

```
userId    logon_date              logoff_date
1         2012-01-01 10:00:00     2012-01-01 12:00:00
1         2012-01-01 09:00:00     NULL
```

Because there is a **newer** logon_date of 2012-01-01 10:00:00, I know that the user must have killed the session for the login_date of 2012-01-01 09:00:00.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT userId, logon_date, logoff_date
FROM user_logon
WHERE user_id = 2
```

What I would like is to count only active sessions. In order to do this, I need to skip the rows where the logoff_date is missing if there is a newer row with the same userId.

Comment: Do you have auto increment primary key in this table?

Comment: @zerkms, no, it's not auto_increment. I'm using the session hash for the primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
    SELECT l.*
      FROM user_logon l
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(logon_date) mdate,
                   user_id
              FROM user_logon
          GROUP BY user_id) x ON x.user_id = l.user_id
                             AND l.logon_date = x.mdate
     WHERE l.logoff_date IS NULL
```

?

PS: This query implies that for each date there is only one record for particular user

Comment: Serk, thank you... Let me try this and I'll let you know how this works out. brb

Comment: Zerk, I'm getting no rows back from this query. I just saw your edit and this table holds all logins so there will be many rows per user.

Comment: @Mr. Overflow: uhm, I don't believe, it should work. Does inner query return something?

Comment: Zerk, I extracted your inner query and it returns 2 rows. Thanks again for this help. Can this be done>?

Comment: @Mr. Overflow: if it returns 2 rows - then you only have 2 different users in that table and no one has active session. Please double check it, because query should be fine